# How to create Genie MVC app with Oracle DB as backend?

Tags: oracle, julia, genie.jl

I am trying to create a new MVC application with Oracle DB as backend with DB Option 4(Others).

```
julia> Genie.newapp_mvc("WatchTonight")
```

But, getting the following error:

```
┌ Error: Pkg.Types.PkgError("The following package names could not be resolved:\n * SearchLightOracle (not found in project, manifest or registry)\n")
```

I tried to install package SearchLightOracle.
But, package not found:

```
(WatchTonight) pkg> add SearchLightOracle
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * SearchLightOracle (not found in project, manifest or registry)
```

Please guide me in creating Genie web app with Oracle DB as backend.

full logs:

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.6.4 (2021-11-19)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> using Genie

julia> Genie.newapp_mvc("WatchTonight")
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
   Resolving package versions...
  No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.6/Project.toml`
  No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.6/Manifest.toml`
Please choose the DB backend you want to use: 
1. SQLite
2. MySQL
3. PostgreSQL
4. Other
Input 1, 2, 3 or 4 and press ENTER to confirm

4
Please input DB adapter (ex: Oracle, ODBC, JDBC, etc)

Oracle
  Activating environment at `~/Project.toml`
┌ Error: Pkg.Types.PkgError("The following package names could not be resolved:\n * SearchLightOracle (not found in project, manifest or registry)\n")
└ @ Genie.Generator ~/.julia/packages/Genie/fMBsZ/src/Generator.jl:503
[ Info: Done! New app created at /root/WatchTonight
[ Info: Changing active directory to /root/WatchTonight
    /tmp/jl_Z2oGzp/WatchTonight/Project.toml
[ Info: Project.toml has been generated
[ Info: Installing app dependencies
  Activating environment at `~/WatchTonight/Project.toml`
   Resolving package versions...
   Installed Crayons ────────── v4.1.0
   Installed LoweredCodeUtils ─ v2.2.0
   Installed JuliaInterpreter ─ v0.9.0
   Installed Revise ─────────── v3.3.1
    Updating `~/WatchTonight/Project.toml`
  [c43c736e] + Genie v4.7.1
  [6d011eab] + Inflector v1.0.1
  [e6f89c97] + LoggingExtras v0.4.7
  [739be429] + MbedTLS v1.0.3
  [ade2ca70] + Dates
  [56ddb016] + Logging
    Updating `~/WatchTonight/Manifest.toml`
  [c7e460c6] + ArgParse v1.1.4
  [00ebfdb7] + CSTParser v3.3.0
  [da1fd8a2] + CodeTracking v1.0.6
  [a80b9123] + CommonMark v0.8.5
  [34da2185] + Compat v3.41.0
  [a8cc5b0e] + Crayons v4.1.0
  [864edb3b] + DataStructures v0.18.11
  [8f5d6c58] + EzXML v1.1.0
  [48062228] + FilePathsBase v0.9.17
  [c43c736e] + Genie v4.7.1
  [cd3eb016] + HTTP v0.9.17
  [77172c1b] + HttpCommon v0.5.0
  [6d011eab] + Inflector v1.0.1
  [83e8ac13] + IniFile v0.5.0
  [692b3bcd] + JLLWrappers v1.3.0
  [682c06a0] + JSON v0.21.2
  [0f8b85d8] + JSON3 v1.9.2
  [98e50ef6] + JuliaFormatter v0.20.5
  [aa1ae85d] + JuliaInterpreter v0.9.0
  [e6f89c97] + LoggingExtras v0.4.7
  [6f1432cf] + LoweredCodeUtils v2.2.0
  [739be429] + MbedTLS v1.0.3
  [39ec1447] + Millboard v0.2.5
  [49dea1ee] + Nettle v0.5.1
  [4d1e1d77] + Nullables v1.0.0
  [bac558e1] + OrderedCollections v1.4.1
  [69de0a69] + Parsers v2.1.3
  [21216c6a] + Preferences v1.2.3
  [92933f4c] + ProgressMeter v1.7.1
  [189a3867] + Reexport v1.2.2
  [ae029012] + Requires v1.2.0
  [295af30f] + Revise v3.3.1
  [6c6a2e73] + Scratch v1.1.0
  [69024149] + StringEncodings v0.3.5
  [856f2bd8] + StructTypes v1.8.1
  [b718987f] + TextWrap v1.0.1
  [0796e94c] + Tokenize v0.5.21
  [30578b45] + URIParser v0.4.1
  [5c2747f8] + URIs v1.3.0
  [856ac37a] + UrlDownload v1.0.0
  [a637dc6b] + VersionCheck v0.2.0
  [ddb6d928] + YAML v0.4.7
  [94ce4f54] + Libiconv_jll v1.16.1+1
  [4c82536e] + Nettle_jll v3.7.2+0
  [02c8fc9c] + XML2_jll v2.9.12+0
  [0dad84c5] + ArgTools
  [56f22d72] + Artifacts
  [2a0f44e3] + Base64
  [ade2ca70] + Dates
  [8bb1440f] + DelimitedFiles
  [8ba89e20] + Distributed
  [f43a241f] + Downloads
  [7b1f6079] + FileWatching
  [b77e0a4c] + InteractiveUtils
  [b27032c2] + LibCURL
  [76f85450] + LibGit2
  [8f399da3] + Libdl
  [37e2e46d] + LinearAlgebra
  [56ddb016] + Logging
  [d6f4376e] + Markdown
  [a63ad114] + Mmap
  [ca575930] + NetworkOptions
  [44cfe95a] + Pkg
  [de0858da] + Printf
  [3fa0cd96] + REPL
  [9a3f8284] + Random
  [ea8e919c] + SHA
  [9e88b42a] + Serialization
  [1a1011a3] + SharedArrays
  [6462fe0b] + Sockets
  [2f01184e] + SparseArrays
  [10745b16] + Statistics
  [fa267f1f] + TOML
  [a4e569a6] + Tar
  [8dfed614] + Test
  [cf7118a7] + UUIDs
  [4ec0a83e] + Unicode
  [781609d7] + GMP_jll
  [deac9b47] + LibCURL_jll
  [29816b5a] + LibSSH2_jll
  [c8ffd9c3] + MbedTLS_jll
  [14a3606d] + MozillaCACerts_jll
  [83775a58] + Zlib_jll
  [8e850ede] + nghttp2_jll
  [3f19e933] + p7zip_jll
Precompiling project...
  ✓ JuliaInterpreter
  ✓ Crayons
  ✓ CommonMark
  ✓ LoweredCodeUtils
  ✓ JuliaFormatter
  ✓ Revise
  ✓ Genie
  9 dependencies successfully precompiled in 120 seconds (41 already precompiled)
  7 dependencies precompiled but different versions are currently loaded. Restart julia to access the new versions
   Resolving package versions...
    Updating `~/WatchTonight/Project.toml`
  [340e8cb6] + SearchLight v2.0.1
    Updating `~/WatchTonight/Manifest.toml`
  [9a962f9c] + DataAPI v1.9.0
  [a93c6f00] + DataFrames v1.3.1
  [e2d170a0] + DataValueInterfaces v1.0.0
  [59287772] + Formatting v0.4.2
  [41ab1584] + InvertedIndices v1.1.0
  [82899510] + IteratorInterfaceExtensions v1.0.0
  [e1d29d7a] + Missings v1.0.2
  [2dfb63ee] + PooledArrays v1.4.0
  [08abe8d2] + PrettyTables v1.3.1
  [340e8cb6] + SearchLight v2.0.1
  [a2af1166] + SortingAlgorithms v1.0.1
  [3783bdb8] + TableTraits v1.0.1
  [bd369af6] + Tables v1.6.1
  [9fa8497b] + Future
Precompiling project...
  ✓ LoweredCodeUtils
  ✓ JuliaFormatter
  ✓ Revise
  ✓ Genie
  6 dependencies successfully precompiled in 105 seconds (57 already precompiled)
  4 dependencies precompiled but different versions are currently loaded. Restart julia to access the new versions
Please choose the DB backend you want to use: 
1. SQLite
2. MySQL
3. PostgreSQL
4. Other
Input 1, 2, 3 or 4 and press ENTER to confirm

4
Please input DB adapter (ex: Oracle, ODBC, JDBC, etc)

Oracle
  Activating environment at `~/WatchTonight/Project.toml`
┌ Error: Pkg.Types.PkgError("The following package names could not be resolved:\n * SearchLightOracle (not found in project, manifest or registry)\n")
└ @ Genie.Generator ~/.julia/packages/Genie/fMBsZ/src/Generator.jl:503
[ Info: Installing dependencies for unit tests
  Activating new environment at `~/WatchTonight/test/Project.toml`
   Resolving package versions...
    Updating `~/WatchTonight/test/Project.toml`
  [8dfed614] + Test
    Updating `~/WatchTonight/test/Manifest.toml`
  [2a0f44e3] + Base64
  [b77e0a4c] + InteractiveUtils
  [56ddb016] + Logging
  [d6f4376e] + Markdown
  [9a3f8284] + Random
  [9e88b42a] + Serialization
  [8dfed614] + Test
  Activating environment at `~/WatchTonight/Project.toml`
[ Info: Starting your brand new Genie app - hang tight!
[ Info: Precompiling WatchTonight [93f46181-df21-4b6e-b7cd-33e5e979776f]

 _____         _
|   __|___ ___|_|___
|  |  | -_|   | | -_|
|_____|___|_|_|_|___|

| Web: https://genieframework.com
| GitHub: https://github.com/genieframework/Genie.jl
| Docs: https://genieframework.github.io/Genie.jl/dev
| Gitter: https://gitter.im/essenciary/Genie.jl
| Twitter: https://twitter.com/GenieMVC

Active env: DEV


Ready! 

┌ Info: 2022-01-06 10:38:26 
└ Web Server starting at http://127.0.0.1:8000 

julia>
```

Comment: @AVA, to avoid having your questions closed by cranky old programmers outside the Julia community, I’d recommend not tagging them with tags that aren’t specific to Julia. Yes, this makes stack overflow worse for everyone but it’s an extremely consistent toxic behavior on the site that we can’t really change and can only work around.

Comment: I'm the author of the SearchlightOracle.jl adapter. If you are interested in using it I have to update it to the last changes made in SearchLight.jl itself. Please feel free to create an issue and tell me what you need. For more insides please feel free to ask in the SearchLight section of the Genie channel https://discord.gg/VUaT87D9 . There we can discuss deeply if you have problems to get things up and running. Best Frank

Answer (score 3):

The reason you cannot add the project is that it is not a registered package. To add a non-registered package, you need to do:

```
] add https://github.com/FrankUrbach/SearchLightOracle.jl.git
```

However, I will note that https://github.com/FrankUrbach/SearchLightOracle.jl does not look like it is being actively maintained. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/FrankUrbach/SearchLightOracle.jl/issues/6 for Frank to comment on the state of the project.

You might be able to build off of the existing project by reading the docs: https://github.com/FrankUrbach/SearchLightOracle.jl/blob/master/docs/src/index.md as it appears some functions are working.